# Is there a way to trigger the TTL monitoring on mongodb manually?

Tags: mongodb

Just was wondering if there was a call that could be made to mongodb that would force it to check a collection that has TTL values set? (rather than waiting for when it gets around to it)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know the field with the TTL index and the TTL time you set on it, you can just perform this query. It is essentially what the TTL mechanism does at regular intervals.

```
db.collection.remove({ fieldWithTimeToLiveIndex: { $lt: new Date() - TTLTime } });
```

Comment: Hmmm...that almost works (also very good to know).  My use case is that I want to test that the built-in mechanism will flush things out as expected. (but want to trigger it rather than wait for it to run on its own)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that? The TTL monitor is no tool to limit results, but to clean up your database. So instead of triggering TTL manually, limit your results in your queries:

```
db.collection.find({..., dateField: {$gt: someExpirationDate} })
```

This has the advantage that it is more reliable, since it would not return results which are just about to be deleted, but nor yet are.

Comment: eg. I give you some instructions, I then wait to see if I've written those instructions in a way you understand, but I'd like you to do it now, not when you feel like it.

Comment: giving you instructions, and then going in and interpreting them myself doesn't help me verify that they are in a format you understand.